# Claim a stake or stake a claim?

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Which of the following is a correct usage?

> CLAIM A STAKE

or

> STAKE A CLAIM

I am highly confused about these two. How to use them in sentences? Though the first one appears to be correct to me, the dictionary suggests the second. Why? Why is the first one wrong?

Comment: Both can be correct but they may mean slightly different things. Please edit the question to show your own research, so that others don't repeat it. Why do you think the first one should be "correct"? What do want the phrase to mean?

Comment: Welcome to EL & U, @Shameyeta! This is a good question for a start; but the StackExchange sites are built on the assumption that people will tell us any work they've done to find the answer already. Please let us know what you've done to try and find the answer on your own; that will help us supply an answer with appropriate sources for you.

Answer (score 1):

*Staking a claim* is the physical act of marking territory (by driving marked stakes into the ground) over which you have a claim of mineral or other usage rights. It can be metaphorically extended to the sense of "calling dibs" on something. It is likely to be a more common and intuitive phrase in areas that have a significant prospecting or mining tradition that evolved under descendants of English law. *Staking a claim* is asserting exclusive rights which may be granted *de jure* if there are no existing countervailing claims over the same land. Once you have staked a claim, no-one else can make a new claim over the same territory for the same purposes until your claim has expired; you are required to exercise the rights that you have claimed within a certain period of time.

*Claiming a stake*, on the other hand, would probably be better phrased as *claiming a share in the stakes*, where *the stakes* means a gambling or investment pool, or the expected returns on that pool.

Comment: Claiming a stake could also just be finding an unused stake lying about, and then claiming it as your own. ;-)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet - there's always the degenerate case, isn't there?